# NLog FileTarget delays LogEventInfo

Tags: c#, nlog

The code

```cs
LogEventInfo theEvent               = new LogEventInfo();
Logger offsetLogger                 = LogManager.GetLogger("ProdDataLog");
theEvent.Properties["Range"]        = calc.Range;
offsetLogger.Log(theEvent);
```

Below is the target

```xml
<target name="ProdDataFile" xsi:type = "File"
    fileName="${prodDataDir}ProdFile.csv"
    archiveFileName="${prodDataDir}Archive/ProdFile.{#}.csv"
    archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
    archiveAboveSize="500000" archiveEvery="Day" maxArchiveFiles="30"
    archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd">
      <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout" delimiter="Comma" withHeader="true" quoting="Nothing">
        <column name="Date"           layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}" />
        <column name="Time"           layout="${time:HH:mm:ss.ffff}" />
        <column name="Range"          layout="${event-properties:Range}" />
      </layout>
</target>
```

And the rule

```xml
   <logger name="ProdDataLog"  writeTo="ProdDataFile"   final="true" />
```

The problem is the function

```
offsetLogger.Log(theEvent);
```

can take up to 200-300 ms.

Normal logs dont have the delay....but trying to create a csv log.

Any ideas?
I tried adding 'async' to the targets but then the csv wasn't written to at all.

Answer (score 0):

[NLog FileTarget](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target) uses `KeepFileOpen=false` by default, as it works across platforms and works with most file-viewers/monitors. But the performance is bad.

Try adding `KeepFileOpen="true"` like this:

```xml
<target name="ProdDataFile" xsi:type = "File"
   keepFileOpen="true"
   fileName="${prodDataDir}ProdFile.csv"
   archiveFileName="${prodDataDir}Archive/ProdFile.{#}.csv"
   archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
   archiveAboveSize="500000" archiveEvery="Day" maxArchiveFiles="30"
   archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd">
  <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout" delimiter="Comma" withHeader="true" quoting="Nothing">
    <column name="Date"           layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}" />
    <column name="Time"           layout="${time:HH:mm:ss.ffff}" />
    <column name="Range"          layout="${event-properties:Range}" />
  </layout>
</target>
```

Alternative you can use `<targets async="true">` (Recommended if having many threads writing to the same File-Target). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Performance#file-logging-performance and [Remember to Flush](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#5-remember-to-flush)